# Is the use of "feel" followed by "would" incorrect in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, will-would

I am talking about a feeling that could possibly arise in a hypothetical future situation, and if the feeling did arise, the person would express it. I phrased the sentence like this: "If you feel that way in the future, you would express/say it." Is my use of the word "would" after "feel" incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

It should be either:

> If you were to feel that way in the future, you would express it.

The conditional mood of *should* is usually paired to a hypothetical, which is expressed with *were to*. However, in informal speaking, people tend to avoid *were to*. They would often say:

> If you felt that way in the future, you would express it.

If you use a more definite auxiliary like *will* or *should*, you can then use *feel* without qualification:

> If you feel that way in the future, you should express it.

or

> When you feel that way in the future, you will express it.